# Apache Quantum Uncertainty Principle... If directive both true and false

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

The value of the environment variable is set in bash:

```
# export PRODUCTION=true
# echo $PRODUCTION
# true
```

Here is the relevant excerpt from my virtual host file:

```
<If "-T osenv('PRODUCTION')">
  Define dogs dogs
</If>
<Else>
  Define cats cats
</Else>
```

`apache2ctl -S` produces:

```
Define: dogs=dogs
Define: cats=cats
```

Thus, we have a quantum conditional that is **both true and false**. What is going on here and how do I get it to behave normally?

I can't find anything in these references that indicates that I am doing something wrong.

- [apache if-else](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#else)
- [apache urnary operators](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#unnop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `apachectl -S` it is just parsing the code to make sure it is syntactically correct, it is not actually executing the code. The output is just telling you the things that can happen not the result of evaluating the if/else block.

You can verify this by actually having an active Apache directive in your if and else blocks. For example:

```
<If "-T osenv('PRODUCTION')">
  Define dogs dogs
  Header set MyHeader1 "PRODUCTION defined %D %t"
</If>
<Else>
  Define cats cats
  Header set MyHeader2 "PRODUCTION undefined %D %t"
</Else>
```

And you start you Apache with or without PRODCUTION defined, you will see the different header in the responses from your server. The `%D` and `%t` are there to add something that changes with each request so that you do not think you are getting something cached somehow.

Please note, for this to work you **must** do a full stop and start in between setting/unsetting the PRODUCTION environment variable, restart will not work.